# Extract numbers from String and add them

Tags: java, arrays, string

For my school, I have to create an `add` function which can add 2 numbers.

Example: `/add 6 4`
Solution: `10`

This is my code at the moment, which lets me do that, but only with at maximum `/add 9 9`:

```
String stString = message_text;
String number = stString.replaceAll("[^0-9]", "");
int numArr[] = new int[2];
for (int i = 0; i<2; i++) {
    numArr[i] = Integer.parseInt(String.valueOf(number.charAt(i)));
}

int sum = IntStream.of(numArr).sum();
```

I need a way to be able to make it that I could use `/add 14 23` or so.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow.  You want to [`String#split()`](http://download.java.net/java/jdk9/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#split-java.lang.String-) your original string.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why don't you use split like this:

```
String[] myValues = stString.split(" ");
```

And after that get the values by myValues[1] and myValues[2]

Answer (score 1):

Can't write your homework for you, but look at your logic. If you only read a single character, you can only ever have a single digit.

Parse for multidigit inputs instead of using `charAt()`. Take a few extra lines of code to collect and build your inputs. Try `String.substring()` or `String.split()` and work from there.

Answer (score 1):

Since you are already using streams, you could make a 1-liner stream-only solution:

```
int sum = Stream.of(stString.split(" ")).
    skip(1).
    mapToInt(Integer::parseInt).
    sum();
```

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is that you are complicating it too much with `replace()`, `String.valueOf()` and `IntStream.of(numArr).sum()`, and then you limit your program to read only one character, so your numbers will be always composed of only one digit.

**Solution:**

You just need to use `.split()` method and pass to it a space as delimiter:

```
String stString = "/add 64 10";
int a = Integer.parseInt(stString.split(" ")[1]);
int b = Integer.parseInt(stString.split(" ")[2]);
System.out.println(a+b); //will print 74
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem with your approach is that you confuse the index of the required numbers in the `String` with their actual index in the `String`. 
Essentially you want two numbers but you always look for two consecutive digits after your replacement.

One way to work around this would be to use a simple regular expression to fetch 1+ digit sequences and collect them.

For instance:

```
String[] test = {
        "/add 1 2",
        "/add 22 20"
    };
Pattern digits = Pattern.compile("\\d+");
for (String s: test) {
    // parsing after /add
    String sequence = s.substring(4);
    // matching digits
    Matcher m = digits.matcher(sequence);
    // finding as many numbers as possible - you can always hard-limit to 2 if needed
    long sum = 0;
    while (m.find()) {
        // no need to check parsing, it will always be integer figures at this point
        sum += Integer.parseInt(m.group());
    }
    System.out.println(sum);
}
```

**Output**

```
3
42
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use split string instead and then convert the fragments into numbers:

```
    String stString = "/add 14 56";
    String[] fragments = stString.split(" ");
    int sum = 0;
    // Start from fragment 1 assuming that fragment 0 is "/add"
    for (int i = 1; i < fragments.length; i++)
        try {
            sum += Integer.valueOf(fragments[i]);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.err.println("Something went wrong converting the strings into integers.");
            System.err.println("Please check the input string.");
            System.err.println("\n");
            e.printStackTrace();
            break;
        }
```